# ereg works but preg_match does not and i'm using the delimiters

Tags: php

I have an ereg statment here that works:

```
if (!ereg('[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+', $_POST["customermemail"]))
        {
            echo "Email address is not valid";
            exit;
        }
```

so if the email is all lowercase (I know thats not a good regex for email), I get false and it does not run the true block.

This is the problem:

```
if (!preg_match('/[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/', $_POST["customermemail"]))
        {
            echo "Email address is not valid";
            exit;
        }
```

This results as false even when I enter an email address that the ereg outputted as true.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Works for me - see https://3v4l.org/MPPeQ. Btw don't you have a typo in array index `customeremail` vs `customer_m_email`?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil...OOPS it was the typo....guess I should get some sleep.  Thanks =)